# jquery ui show slide divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am attempting to have a link "onclick" js event that slides a specific div left. The following jsfiddle works if going from the first link through the third in that order. If going backwards, the div does not slide... I attempted re-zindexing so the div to slide is on top of the currently visible div, but that seems to not work.

http://jsfiddle.net/3qvro2pq/5/

```
function doShow(inDiv){
    $(inDiv).zIndex(1);
    $(inDiv).show({
    effect:'slide',
    direction:'right',
    duration:1000,
    complete:closeHidden
});
}
```

Please help.

Comment: I don't think the fiddle is working? Or atleast not on mac chrome/ff.

Comment: Your demo is broken.

Comment: Sorry... wrong jsfiddle version. My broken code should be "working" now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hide the other divs when the animation start, not when it is completet. Your code works, but the slide is not visible, because the active layer is on top until the animation finishes.

```
var curWindow;
function doShow(inDiv){
    curWindow = inDiv;
    $(inDiv).zIndex(1);
    closeHidden();
    $(inDiv).show({
        effect:'slide',
        direction:'right',
        duration:1000
    });
}
function closeHidden(){
    $(".frameDiv").each(function(i){
        if ("#" + this.id !== curWindow){
            $("#" + this.id).hide();
            $("#" + this.id).zIndex(99);
        }
    });
}
```

Here this works: http://jsfiddle.net/3qvro2pq/7/

**EDIT**: If you want to show the div until the animation is finished, set the zIndex **before** the animation starts and hide on **complete**.

**EDIT2:** This works.

```
var curWindow;
function doShow(inDiv){
    curWindow = inDiv;
    $('.frameDiv').zIndex(1);
    $(inDiv).zIndex(10);
    $(inDiv).show({
        effect:'slide',
        direction:'right',
        duration:1000,
        complete: closeHidden
    });
}
function closeHidden(){
    $(".frameDiv").each(function(i){
        if ("#" + this.id !== curWindow){
            $("#" + this.id).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3qvro2pq/9/

Comment: Unfortunately not the answer, but thanks for the fast response. See the following. http://jsfiddle.net/3qvro2pq/6/

Comment: That part was missed in porting the code from my development to jsfiddle.

Comment: @frustratedITGuy Edited, check it please.

Comment: That is what I was trying to account for when setting the zindex. If I "hide" the divs before the "show" it wont slide over the currently selected DIV.. ie. I want "first" to slide over "third" when clicking the first after third was displayed.